# PHP: Comparing Texts Issues

Tags: php

Consider the case:

- several versions of a text document
- a list with metrics comparing such versions is requested by the client

For texts shorter than 5k characters, this can be easily done on the fly via `similar_text` function. However, for longer texts the execution time becomes a problem:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| number of characters | execution time (s) |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 10k                  | 1                  |
| 20k                  | 3                  |
| 30k                  | 9                  |
| 40k                  | 12                 |
| 50k                  | 20                 |
| 60k                  | 30                 |
| 65k                  | **timeout**        |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

**Note:** 65k is an important milestone since it is, approximately, the maximum length size of TEXT field type in MySQL.

Therefore, for longer texts it is not possible to use `similar_text` on the fly. A possible **workaround** would be to previously populate a table with such `similar_text` metrics and later just retrieve them to the client.

**Questions**

1. Most likely this aforementioned workaround would require a long execution time. Any recommendation to avoid a 'maximum execution time limit' error?
2. Which one is recommended for this workaround: cronjob or background script? other?
3. Is there a simpler way to do such comparisons?

Comment: Just a thought.. possibly break the text into smaller chunks to compare.

Comment: @Scott _"break the text into smaller chunks to compare."_ Perfect, I totally agree. Unfortunately, I don't know any algorithm to do that.

Comment: Just substrings come to mind: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php or chunk split http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php

Comment: @Scott These functions split the text in predefined positions. But this is not the difficult part. The difficult part is choosing the right position to split both texts and how to join the metrics afterwards. Ex: `similar_text('Stack', 'Overflow') => 0%` but `similar_text('Stack Overflow', 'Overflow Stack') => 60%`.

Comment: What do you mean by similar_text? Does the text has to be equal to be similar?

Comment: @SagarTamang _"What do you mean by similar_text?"_ It is a PHP function: [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use cosine similarity to measure the similarity between two strings.
You can read more about it here. [Cosine Similarity](https://blog.nishtahir.com/2015/09/19/fuzzy-string-matching-using-cosine-similarity/)

A rudimentary code is implemented in PHP for your reference.

```
<?php
/**
    Convert string to array/vector of ASCII values of the characters

    @param1 $words String to be converted to the array/vector of ASCII values
    @param2 $output Stores the output array/vector of ASCII values
    @return Magnitude of the vector/array
*/
function convert_to_vector($words, &$output) {
    $magnitude = 0;

    $output = [];

    $length = strlen($words);

    for($i = 0 ; $i < $length; $i++){
        $char = substr($words, $i, 1);
        $ascii = ord($char);
        $magnitude += pow($ascii, 2);
        array_push($output, $ascii);
    }

    return sqrt($magnitude);
}

/**
    * Calculate dot product of two vectors/arrays
    @param1 $a Vector/Array A
    @param2 $b Vector/Array B
    @return dot product of two vectors/arrays
*/
function dot($a, $b){
    $magnitude = 0;

    $length_a = count($a);
    $length_b = count($b);


    $length = ($length_a <= $length_b)? $length_a : $length_b;

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $magnitude += $a[$i] * $b[$i];
    }

    return $magnitude;
}

// Declare two vector/arrays
$output_a = array();
$output_b = array();

// Calculate the magnitude of the vectors
$magnitude_a = convert_to_vector($a,$output_a);
$magnitude_b = convert_to_vector($b,$output_b);

// Calculate the dot vector of two vectors/arrays
$dot_ab = dot($output_a, $output_b);

// Calculate the cosine similarity
// The similarity scores is between 0 to 1. O being unequal and 1 being equal.
$similarity = $dot_ab / ($magnitude_a * $magnitude_b);
$similarity_percent =  $similarity * 100.0;
?>
```

Comment: Very interesting this `cosine similarity`. Indeed it is an alternative much faster than `similar_text`. However, there is a problem. I've tried the following test cases:

Comment: @MarkMessa What is the problem? What were your test cases?

Comment: 1) `$a = random 10k chars text` and `$b = 'x'.$b`. similar_text gives 99.99% match, while cosine similarity gives 90% match.

Comment: 2) `$a = random 10k chars text` and `$b = random 10k chars text`. similar_text gives 10% match, while cosine similarity gives 90% match.

Comment: Based on this two simple test cases, I presume that the metrics provided by cosine similarity is very limited. It could not distinguish texts completely different from each other from texts only slightly different from each other.

Comment: @MarkMessa Yeah, you are right. I think it should only be used, if you are ready to sacrifice speed for accuracy.

Comment: Because of that, unfortunately, I can not use it for long texts. However, this doesn't mean that cosine similarity is useless. Probably there are some applications for it related to dictionary lookups (single/compound words).

Comment: @MarkMessa Your text is basically sentences. I mean they are english paragraphs, aren't they?

Comment: _"if you are ready to sacrifice speed for accuracy."_ Ok, agree. In this case, however, it seems that the accuracy loss was too much.

Comment: _"I mean they are english paragraphs, aren't they?"_ Currently I'm testing with an 'Lorem Ipsum' generator. But the final version would probably be populated with english paragraphs and other conventional chars set.

Comment: @MarkMessa I will look into it again or you can look it for yourself https://towardsdatascience.com/word-to-vectors-natural-language-processing-b253dd0b0817